# Banana PI M1 built-in microphone features

Tags: android, audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian, banana-pi

i would like to obtain information about Banana PI M1 built-in microphone features. It would be nice to know its maximum sampling frequency (I know it samples at 44100 Hz, could it get any highter?) and i also require (if existing) some frequency response charts. Is there such a thing like an expansion (addon board) microphone for this device. Could an usb microphone work? If I install Android on this device, could i access to the microphone features with a customized app for this purpose? Thanks

Comment: I installed Android on it and tasted sound recording features with several apps such as "All that recorder" and "Tape machine". The maximum allowed samplig frequency was 48000 Hz. i don´t know if this is an operative system or hardware limitation. I checked the spectrum with "Spectrum Analyzer" and it turned out to be pretty flat up to 21 kHz where the anti-aliasing filter atenuating region was observed